# Loop in ModelBuilder in a specific situation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, loop, iteration

I would like to make a loop in the next model

[image]

base on a expression, this expression received a code with consecutive numbers in a reference layer call "sector",
to summarize, for each "code" do a "intersect" and create a new feature class made by "base selected"
I tried with for iterator and while but it does not work pretty well

And how can I change the final name in the new feature class made in a new geodatabase without doing it manually every time?

I know its something related %Name%*intersect*%n% but I would like that have the same name that the feature in "beselected"

---

I found some kind of solution, i made a "For loop" with a code in U_SECTOR , but unfortunately works in numbers that at the end of the code has between 10 to 99 or adding a 0 in the code i could find a numbers between 1 to 9
i would like to try how can i do the same iteraction whit diferents layers whitout adding manualy at the model

[image]
[image]